# How much more damage is a "critical" XMP burster hit?

Tags: ingress

Sometimes when using XMP Bursters you see that you have scored a "critical" hit on an enemy resonator. Does anyone know the likelihood of a critical hit taking place and how much more damage (ie. is it double a normal hit) it causes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it means that your XMP make double damages.

> Critical just means double damage.  So for example a L1 burster at
>   zero distance will do 300 damage rather than 150.  That's what I have
>   been observing.  This doubling is affected by distance.  As the damage
>   is relative to resonator energy/level and it's rounded up to a minimum
>   of 1% (even if it's 0.2% for example when hiting a high level
>   resonator with a level 1 burster) you get those critical 1% hits.

[source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ingress-discuss/wIzPNePt0Eo)